# For loop doesn't work properly for unknown reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter

I have this code:

```
def show_hide(a, b, c, d):
    if not b[0]["text"]:  # check if text's length is 0
        b[0].configure(text="{}".format(d[0]), bd=2, bg="white", command=lambda: activate_deactivate(a[0], c[0]))  # configure button_1
        c[0]["text"] = "Status: {}".format(a[0].get())  # set text for label_1
        b[1].configure(text="{}".format(d[1]), bd=2, bg="white", command=lambda: activate_deactivate(a[1], c[1]))  # configure button_2
        c[1]["text"] = "Status: {}".format(a[1].get())  # set text for label_2
    else:
        b[0].configure(text="", bd=0, bg="#F0F0F0", command=None)  # hide the button_1
        c[0]["text"] = ""  # hide the label_1
        b[1].configure(text="", bd=0, bg="#F0F0F0", command=None)  # hide the button_2
        c[1]["text"] = ""  # hide the label_2
```

My button which calls this function has this command value:

```
command=lambda: show_hide([status, status_2], [button, button_2], [label, label_2], ["Perform action #1", "Perform action #2"]))
```

By using it I can show/hide buttons but rewriting the same thing changing a digit in a few places would be tedious. To fix it I tried using this code instead of the original:

```
def show_hide(a, b, c, d):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):  # iterates over indexes of items in a,b,c,d lists (all 4 have same length) and passes them to the if/else statement
        if not b[i]["text"]:  # check if text length is 0
            b[i].configure(text="{}".format(d[i]), bd=2, bg="white", command=lambda: activate_deactivate(a[i], c[i]))  # configure buton
            c[i]["text"] = "Status: {}".format(a[i].get())  # set label's text
        else:
            b[i].configure(text="", bd=0, bg="#F0F0F0", command=None)  # hide button
            c[i]["text"] = ""  # hide label
```

Theoretically, this should work fine and using just 4 lines of code (not counting for/if/else lines) do the same thing as original function which would need 4 lines for EACH status+button+label created. BUT, as a matter of fact, it makes my 2 buttons work totally wrong.

I don't really understand what is wrong with it so I can't fully describe the problem, but you can see for yourself by using the test-script I made and replacing the show_hide function definition with the one using for-loop:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class ActionButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(text="", font="courier 20", bd=0)


class ActionLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(text="", font="courier 14")


def multi(*args):
    for func in args:
        return func


def show_hide(a, b, c, d):
    if not b[0]["text"]:
        b[0].configure(text="{}".format(d[0]), bd=2, bg="white", command=lambda: activate_deactivate(a[0], c[0]))
        c[0]["text"] = "Status: {}".format(a[0].get())
        b[1].configure(text="{}".format(d[1]), bd=2, bg="white", command=lambda: activate_deactivate(a[1], c[1]))
        c[1]["text"] = "Status: {}".format(a[1].get())
    else:
        b[0].configure(text="", bd=0, bg="#F0F0F0", command=None)
        c[0]["text"] = ""
        b[1].configure(text="", bd=0, bg="#F0F0F0", command=None)
        c[1]["text"] = ""


def activate_deactivate(a, c):
    if a.get() == "Can be done":
        a.set("To be done")
        c.configure(text="Status: {}".format(a.get()), fg="blue")
    else:
        a.set("Can be done")
        c.configure(text="Status: {}".format(a.get()), fg="black")


def step_forward(a, b, c):
    if a.get() == "To be done":
        b.configure(text="", bd=0, bg="#F0F0F0", state="disabled")
        c["text"] = ""
        result = random.choice(["success", "failure"])
        if result == "success":
            a.set("Accomplished")
            c["fg"] = "green"
        else:
            a.set("Failed")
            c["fg"] = "red"
    else:
        b.configure(text="", bd=0, bg="#F0F0F0", command=None)
        c["text"] = ""


root = tk.Tk()

status = tk.StringVar()
status.set("Can be done")

status_2 = tk.StringVar()
status_2.set("Can be done")

main = tk.Button(root, text="Show/Hide", bg="white", font="courier 30",
                 command=lambda: show_hide([status, status_2],
                                           [button, button_2],
                                           [label, label_2],
                                           ["Perform action #1", "Perform action #2"]))
main.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, pady=10)
frame.pack()

frame_1 = tk.Frame(frame, padx=10)
frame_1.pack(side="left")

frame_2 = tk.Frame(frame, padx=10)
frame_2.pack(side="left")

button = ActionButton(frame_1)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

label = ActionLabel(frame_1)
label.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_2 = ActionButton(frame_2)
button_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

label_2 = ActionLabel(frame_2)
label_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

next_day = tk.Button(root, text="Next day", bg="white", font="courier 30",
                     command=lambda: multi(step_forward(status, button, label),
                                           step_forward(status_2, button_2, label_2)))
next_day.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope there's someone who may know how to fix this and maybe even has an idea about how the function could be changed to perform everything properly.

Comment: is it common problem with `lambda` in `for` loop ? (because `lambda` is `"lazy"`)

Comment: Why are you calling `lambda` which are used for anonymous functions when you have declared, named functions? Try removing all of them.

Comment: @Parfait Lambdas are used to assign functions to buttons but not call them instantly. If I remove lambda (I actually tried), the functions I use get called with the start of the program and buttons become totally useless.

Comment: You should be enclosing your functions in a class object for that very reason.